# Finding current open file path in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I need to sign the scripts I write within ISE to run them. How can I get the path of the current open file in the active tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath
```

Is the path to the file. It can be signed with a command like this:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath $certificate
```

ISE won't refresh to show the added signature text though, so consider including these commands to close and re-open the file:

```
$file = $psISE.CurrentFile
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Remove($file)
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Add($file.FullPath)
```